# How to select random vertices in Gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin

I'm still at my earlier stages with graphs and gremlin.

Is it possible to randomly select graph vertices in Gremlin?

Consider the following pipeline that gets the cars owned by a user's friend:

`u.out('Friend')[0..9].out('Drives').map()`

But this code is only executed against the first 10 friends every time. How can I make the selection random efficiently?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Seems we could create a general purpose pipe that takes the desired number of elements as an argument and iterates through all input and then returns that number of randomly selected elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `shuffle`:

```
 g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
 gremlin> g.v(1).out.shuffle[0]
 ==>v[3]
 gremlin> g.v(1).out.shuffle[0]
 ==>v[2]
 gremlin> g.v(1).out.shuffle[0]
 ==>v[3]
 gremlin> g.v(1).out.shuffle[0]
 ==>v[4]
```

This solution isn't very efficient though since all neighbours of `v(1)` need to be fetched.

This might help as well: [Random Walk on Bipartite Graph with Gremlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783212/random-walk-on-bipartite-graph-with-gremlin)

Answer (score 6):

In Gremlin 2.x you could use [random](http://gremlindocs.com/#filter/random) step as in:

```
g.v(1).out.random()
```

or in 3.x `random` has become [coin](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#coin-step):

as in:

```
g.V(1).out.coin()
```

in 3.x, you might also look at [sample](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#sample-step) and [order(shuffle)](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#order-step) steps in 3.x.